# How can I access a Linux machine over WiFI without an internet connection?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, webserver, wlan

I have a Linux machine that runs a local webserver using this terminal command:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

When deployed in routine operations this machine is not connected to the internet but I would like to establish a WLAN to connect to it from another machine to access the webpage it is serving.

Could anyone suggest how I might be able to go about this? Should I create a hotspot? I've read a bit about the `create_ap` package but it appears that this is no longer maintained so not sure if its the best solution?

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154972/wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu-19-04/1154982#1154982

Comment: I tried that and kept getting a timeout error. I've had more luck following the instructions [here] (https://arnab-k.medium.com/ubuntu-how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode-192cbb2eeb90) actually. Using this approach, I can create an access point that I can see on other devices but I can't successfully connect to it to see whether I can access the webpage being served.